# RestApi testing using Rest-Assured

Tags: rest, rest-assured

I am new to REST-Api testing. i am getting started with Rest-Assured for Rest-Api testing. i am having an issue in my first ever testcase.

The code is as follows:

```
public void testGetSingleUser() {
  expect().
    statusCode(200).
    body(
      "email", equals("test@hascode.com"),
      "firstName", equals("Tim"),
      "lastName", equals("Testerman"),
      "id", equals("1")).
    when().
    get("/service/single-user");
}
```

In this code the "expect()." command is not working. I need to fix this issue quickly and move on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your request can't compile because you forget given() and you have to use equalTo() instead of equals().

Try this request:

```
given().
            expect().
            statusCode(200).
            body("email", equalTo("test@hascode.com")).
            body("firstName", equalTo("Tim")).
            body("lastName", equalTo("Testerman")).
            body("id", equalTo("1")).
        when().
            get("/service/single-user");
```

Also double check your imports:

```
import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
```

Comment: "given" is not needed, the problem is the Hamcrest matcher

Answer (score 0):

We use [RestTest](https://github.com/rawoke083/RestTest) it's an easy free standalone app.

Add all your urls in one file and test conditions.
One line One Test :)

Comment: Besides the link, it would be nice to provide some examples. As, if link will go dead - this post will become useless.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to fix the code and make sure about two imports.

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;

public void testGetSingleUser() {
  given().
      expect().
      statusCode(200).
      body(
       "email", equalTo("test@hascode.com"),
       "firstName", equalTo("Tim"),
       "lastName", equalTo("Testerman"),
       "id", equalTo("1")).
    when().
      get("/service/single-user");
}
```

> **And make sure to add JARs.**